# Force closing when passing variables with intent

Tags: java, android

I am passing variables between classes with intent. I have the following code that works properly

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //startActivity(new Intent("com.th3ramr0d.prtmanager.ONEWEEKDAYTWO"));

            //VARIABLES FOR DAY 1
            EditText d1instructor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wkOneDayOneInstructorName);
            String day1_inst = d1instructor.getText().toString();

            EditText d1uniform = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wkOneDayOneUniform);
            String day1_uniform = d1uniform.getText().toString();

            EditText d1location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wkOneDayOneLocation);
            String day1_location = d1location.getText().toString();

            TimePicker d1hrtime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.wkOneDayOneTime_Picker);
            int d1hours = d1hrtime.getCurrentHour();
            TimePicker d1mintime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.wkOneDayOneTime_Picker);
            int d1min = d1mintime.getCurrentMinute();

            Spinner dOnex1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.wkOneDayOneexOne);
            String d1x1 = (String) dOnex1.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Spinner dOnex2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.wkOneDayOneexTwo);
            String d1x2 = (String) dOnex2.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Spinner dOnex3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.wkOneDayOneexThree);
            String d1x3 = (String) dOnex3.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Spinner dOnex4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.wkOneDayOneexFour);
            String d1x4 = (String) dOnex4.getSelectedItem().toString();

            //PASS CHOSEN DATE
            int day = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("day");
            String month = getIntent().getStringExtra("month");
            int year = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("year");
            String dayofweek = getIntent().getStringExtra("dayofweek");

            //PASS VARIABLES WITH INTENT
            Intent intent = new Intent (OneWeekPlan_Start_Btn.this, Week1Day2.class);

            //PASS VARIABLES FOR DATE SET
            intent.putExtra("day", day);
            intent.putExtra("month", month);
            intent.putExtra("year", year);
            intent.putExtra("dayofweek", dayofweek);

            //PASS VARIABLES FOR DAY 1
            intent.putExtra("day1_inst", day1_inst);
            intent.putExtra("day1_uniform", day1_uniform);
            intent.putExtra("day1_location", day1_location);
            intent.putExtra("d1hours", d1hours);
            intent.putExtra("d1min", d1min);
            intent.putExtra("d1x1", d1x1);
            intent.putExtra("d1x2", d1x2);
            intent.putExtra("d1x3", d1x3);
            intent.putExtra("d1x4", d1x4);  
            startActivity(intent);
```

Right above the PASS CHOSEN DATE comment I enter

```
//VARIABLES FOR DAY 2
EditText d2instructor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wkOneDayTwoInstructorName);
String day2_inst = d2instructor.getText().toString();
```

And then add the intent just above the startActivity(intent);

```
//PASS VARIABLES FOR DAY 2
intent.putExtra("day2_inst", day2_inst);
```

After adding those last 2 blocks of code it force closes when I press my button.

Logcat

```
11-22 18:38:04.385: D/AndroidRuntime(31952): Shutting down VM
11-22 18:38:04.385: W/dalvikvm(31952): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
(group=0x415f6ba8)
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952): Process: com.th3ramr0d.prtmanager, PID: 31952
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952):    at
com.th3ramr0d.prtmanager.OneWeekPlan_Start_Btn$1.onClick(OneWeekPlan_Start_Btn.java:60)
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952):    at 
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952):    at  
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952):    at  
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952):    at    
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native     
Method)
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952):    at     
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952):    at      
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952):    at     
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-22 18:38:04.395: E/AndroidRuntime(31952):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 18:38:05.846: I/Process(31952): Sending signal. PID: 31952 SIG: 9
11-22 18:38:06.117: I/Adreno-EGL(32079): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build:              
I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
11-22 18:38:06.147: D/OpenGLRenderer(32079): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Imma a dummy =( I was trying to get the variables for my second page in the wrong class. I moved those 2 blocks of code

```
//VARIABLES FOR DAY 2
EditText d2instructor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wkOneDayTwoInstructorName);
String day2_inst = d2instructor.getText().toString();
```

and

```
//PASS VARIABLES FOR DAY 2
intent.putExtra("day2_inst", day2_inst);
```

to the next class that was being called and now its working.